# listbox selecteindexchanged

Tags: winforms, listbox

I am new to windows from UI programming. I am using a `listbox` to display data, according to msdn, the `selectedIndexChanged` will happen on `databind` also. (*quoted below*)

What I am trying to do is make another element visible only after a user selects an item in the `listbox`. What is occurring is, as soon as `databind` occurs the element becomes visible.

Should I be using a `listbox`? *(I like the look of the listbox, but I ultimately need something like a webforms dropdownlist)*

How can I make the second element invisible until the user actually selects an item from the `listbox`?

> This event occurs whenever there is a
>   change to a selection. A selection can
>   be changed not only by user
>   interaction but also by binding as
>   well as other set values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind your data to your control and then specify the event handler. Or ignore the events until after the databind has completed. The event is firing correctly and the control is doing what it should. Your code is just getting confused about when it wants to make it visible. It wants it to be visible after it is bound to the control.